# What's the proper way to wrap grpc client behind cobra command?

Tags: go, grpc, go-cobra

I am implementing a GRPC client using cobra. Different service calls are behind the sub-commands.

To avoid code duplication, I keep a single connection and single client in the `viper` singleton. But I am not sure that's the proper way to do it.

Right now, in `cmd/root.go::initConfig()`, I create the connection and client and save them.

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
}
c := pb.NewCommandClient(conn)

viper.SetDefault("Client", c)
viper.SetDefault("Connection", conn)
```

The connection is closed in `rootCmd.PersistentPostRun()`, defined in the same `root.go` file.

```
PersistentPostRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    conn := viper.Get("Connection").(*grpc.ClientConn)
    conn.Close()
},
```

And the client is retrieved from `viper` and used in the sub-commands' `Run` files, for example,

```
c := viper.Get("Client").(pb.CommandClient)
c.DoSomething() // call the service functions on c
```

This implementation works but I am not sure it is good practice. Specifically

1. Is it bad to create the connection in one function and close it in another function?
2. Does it make sense to save the client in `viper` or is it better to create a new one in each sub-command's `Run` function?

All source code is in [this repo](https://github.com/nosarthur/telep)

Comment: 1. Why would it be? Most apps do this. 2. This is a matter of opinion, but if I'm not mistaken viper is meant for configuration management, and a connection pool is definitely not configuration. So it feels a bit like an abuse to me. But that doesn't mean you should create new connections in each `Run` function.

Comment: Where is a good place to save the connection pool and client?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your overall architecture, but this is the sort of thing that [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) can be used for.